Rambam's explanation of eclipses
Following "did-chazal-know-what-caused-eclipses".
In MT, Foundations of the Torah.3.1 and Guide for the Perplexed 1.72, Rambam adapts Ptolemaic geocentrism and Aristotelian view of the planets and the spheres being made of "Quinta Essentia", the fifth element which is "pure and refined like glass or sapphire".
In my understanding, given the planets are transparent luminaries, and not made of earth (as an element), there can be no eclipses.
Did Rambam elaborate on the mechanism of eclipses that fits his views above?

The spheres themselves are transparent. Where does it say that the planets / moon / sun are transparent?

@JoelK Rambam says that the spheres and the luminaries/planets are made of the fifth element. They are not made of earth so they should not block light. Where do you find that they are opaque?

@AlBerko By looking at the sky

Which edition of Moreh are you using?  I heard the edition by MIchael Shwartz Tel Aviv University Press is scholarly enough for these kinds of questions https://seforimcenter.com/RAMBAM---Moreh-HaNevuchim--Targum-Michael-Schwartz-2-vol.__p-8451.aspx

@YDJ The problem is NOT in translation. The planets are not made of earth, but of aether (αἰθήρ) meaning "something clear". That's the Aristotelian and Ptolemaic perception.

@AlBerko I meant not the translation, but a commentary accompanying the translation.
